# How do I compare strings representation of integers?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, compare

I was wondering how I could use an if statement as if they were integers for strings?

```
/**
 * 
 * @param token
 * @return true if parameter is the String representation of an integer
 * between 0 and 255 (including 0 and 255), false otherwise.
 * Strings "0", "1", "2" .... "254", "255" are valid.
 * Padded Strings (such as "00000000153") are also valid 
 */


public static boolean isValidElement(String token) {
    if (token=> 0 || token <=255)
      return true;
    return false; 
}
```

This is what I currently have in mind at the moment but obviously it won't work for strings.

Comment: Convert them into integer for the same radix?

Comment: [Integer.parseInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Comment: Look into `Integer.parseInt()`

Comment: You don't compare apples and oranges, you compare apples and apples or oranges and oranges. In this case, use [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Integer.parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-), but it allows a leading `+`, and that's not allowed according to your javadoc.

You can manually test for leading `+`, then use `Integer.parseInt()` like this:

```
public static boolean isValidElement(String token) {
    if (token == null || token.isEmpty() || token.charAt(0) == '+')
        return false;
    try {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(token);
        return (num >= 0 && num <= 255);
    } catch (@SuppressWarnings("unused") NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

For a high-performance solution that don't rely on `parseInt()` and exception handling, you can use this much longer implementation:

```
public static boolean isValidElement(String token) {
    if (token == null || token.isEmpty())
        return false;
    // skip leading zeroes
    int i = 0;
    while (i < token.length() && token.charAt(i) == '0')
        i++;
    // validate remaining
    char ch;
    switch (token.length() - i) {
        case 0:
            return true; // Allow "0"
        case 1:
            ch = token.charAt(i);
            return (ch >= '1' && ch <= '9'); // Allow "1" to "9"
        case 2:
            ch = token.charAt(i);
            if (ch >= '1' && ch <= '9') {
                ch = token.charAt(i + 1);
                return (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'); // Allow "10" to "99"
            }
            return false;
        case 3:
            ch = token.charAt(i);
            if (ch == '1') {
                ch = token.charAt(i + 1);
                if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
                    ch = token.charAt(i + 2);
                    return (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'); // Allow "100" to "199"
                }
            } else if (ch == '2') {
                ch = token.charAt(i + 1);
                if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '4') {
                    ch = token.charAt(i + 2);
                    return (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9'); // Allow "200" to "249"
                } else if (ch == '5') {
                    ch = token.charAt(i + 2);
                    return (ch >= '0' && ch <= '5'); // Allow "250" to "255"
                }
            }
            return false;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Integer.parseInt(yourString)` for parsing an integer from String. You could try this:

```
   public static boolean isValidElement(String token) {
        try {
            Integer n = Integer.parseInt(token);
            return (n >= 0 && n <= 255);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return false;
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Why is `n` an `Integer`, not an `int`? --- Also, you shouldn't print anything. A non-integer value should simply return `false`, as defined by the javadoc in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(token) >= 0 || Integer.parseInt(token) <= 255) {
    System.out.println(true);
}
```

This will cast the String token using the Integer wrapper class.

Comment: Don't parse twice. Parsing is relatively slow. --- And you're not "casting" anything, you're "parsing".